# How can I select the next two characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var one = "mb50 mt60";
```

How can I put the next two characters after a specific character into its own string?

For example: From the code above, I want the number 50 in its own string. I need it to look for the 'mb', then take the next two characters.

I can't use indexOf because the characters may be in a different place each time.

Comment: dont you want to rather remove 'mb' and 'mt' from the string and explode it with ' '?

Comment: are you trying to find only numbers in a string?

Comment: How does the characters moving mean that you can't use `indexOf`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions, like:

```
var one = "mb50 mt60";
var regex = /mb(\d+)/g;
console.log(regex.exec(one)[1]); // => '50'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing it something like this

```js
var string = "mb50 foo300",
    search = 'foo';

console.log(string.substr(string.indexOf(search) + search.length, 2));
```

or the regex way as Gael suggested.

Answer (score 1):

With a regex like that:

```
str.match(/mb(.{2})/)[1]
```

If there is more than one "next two characters" to capture, you should use replace:

```
var one= "mb50 mt60 mb20";
var results = [];
one.replace(/mb(.{2})/g, function() {
    results.push(arguments[1]);
});
console.log(results);
```